# Convert the first letter of a word to capital using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a query that will make the first letter of the first name a capital and also make the first letter of the last name a capital. I have tried running the query below.

But the output is not correct for example "james plummer"  displays as "James Pames"

```
[FirstName] = UPPER(LEFT(FirstName,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(FirstName,2,LEN(FirstName)))
, [MiddleName]
, [LastName] = UPPER(LEFT(LastName,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(FirstName,2,LEN(LastName)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `sqlserver`, you can use `stuff` function

```
select [FirstName] = stuff(lower(FirstName), 1, 1, upper(left(FirstName, 1)))
    ,[MiddleName]
    ,[LastName] = stuff(lower(LastName), 1, 1, upper(left(LastName, 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats because in your code, for the `[LastName]` you do
`[LastName]=UPPER(LEFT(LastName,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(FirstName,2,LEN(LastName)))`

When you call SUBSTRING you set FirstName instead of LastName,
this causes the LastName to then output as the capitalized first char but ending with the substring of FirstName, which makes a funny combination.

Changing that to:
`[LastName]=UPPER(LEFT(LastName,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(LastName,2,LEN(LastName)))`
Will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

seems you have wrong column  in  lastname `+LOWER(SUBSTRING(FirstName,`

try change to

```
     ,[LastName]=UPPER(LEFT(LastName,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(LastName,2,LEN(LastName)))
```